# build cmake faild Could not find toolchain file: E:/VCPKG/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++17

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

PS D:\C++Test\SakuraAutoCoder> cmake -B build
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- TOOL CHAIN: E:/VCPKG/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems
CMake Error at E:/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:130 (message):
Could not find toolchain file: E:/VCPKG/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)
The complete error report is as shown above,This is the first time I use cmake. Google has not solved this error for a long time.
any help is userful

Comment: Did you set the toolchain to `vcpkg-path/scripts/buildsystems` which is a folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using vcpkg, you can disable toolchain with cmake option -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=OFF.
You can do that globally in vscode settings.json (add "**cmake.configureArgs": ["-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=OFF"]**)

Answer (score 0):

Try
`-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\VCPKG\vcpkg-master\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`

As the name suggests, `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable should point to the **file**, not the directory.

Comment: I entered the command: cmake "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:/VCPKG/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake""
CMake Warning:
 No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.
error message:
-- TOOL CHAIN: /scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
CMake Error at E:/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:130 (message):
Could not find toolchain file: /scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):